# NGINX configuration for API with version and media/static content

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Ok, officially I'm going bonkers here

Trying to configure Nginx (1.14.2) to serve php for an API.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
/var/www/domain/media/ -> holds static image files only

/var/www/domain/v1/
/var/www/domain/v1/public -> front controller sits here (index.php)
/var/www/domain/v1/src -> no accessible from nginx

/var/www/domain/v2/
/var/www/domain/v2/public -> front controller sits here (index.php)
/var/www/domain/v2/src -> no accessible from nginx
```

I have tried using the following:

```
    server {
        
    all the general stuff like logs etc;
          
    location /media {
        root /var/www/domain/media/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
        
    location /v1 {
        root /var/www/domain/v1/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            
        location ~ \.php$ {
            all the fastcgi stuff here;
        }
    }
        
    location /v2 {
        root /var/www/domain/v2/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            
        location ~ \.php$ {
            all the fastcgi stuff here;
        }
        }
    }
```

I have tried various location "filters" but the result seems the same - "Not Found"

Any pointers to where I can find a working example of this?

Thanks
J

Comment: `root /var/www/domain/v1/public` is missing a trailing semicolon. Also it would help if you posted the URIs you are accessing that give you 404

Comment: Danila, thanks just a typo in the post - it's correct in the config file but thanks for pointing it out. 

The URI that works 
https://dev.xxxxxxxx.io/media/avatars/65b1246c35b48-avatar.jpeg

The URIs that don't work: 
https://dev.xxxxxxxx.io/v2/staff/getAllStaff (also tried with / at end)

Answer (score 0):

Ok - took some more reading and trail / error approach.

Firstly because of the project folder structure I don't think it's possible to use "root" in the location blocks. According to the documentation the location will be appended to the "root" you provide.

So in my case:

```
location /v1 {
    root /var/www/domain/v1/public;
}
```

would translate to **/var/www/domain/v1/public/v1** - which doesn't exist.

So using "alias" fixed the issue but had to add a rewrite to force the request to use the front controller.

So the working result is, and please correct me if you think there's a better way - but this seems to work:

```
location ^~ /media {
        alias /var/www/domain_name/dev/media/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

location /v1 {
        alias /var/www/domain_name/dev/v1/public;
        rewrite (.*) /v1/index.php?$query_string;

        location ~* "\.php$" {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        }

}

location /v2 {
        alias /var/www/domain_name/dev/v2/public;
        rewrite (.*) /v2/index.php?$query_string;

        location ~* "\.php$" {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        }

}
```

Thanks
J